# How to add navigator for Y-Axis in Hightstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Now i can add a navigator bar for X-Axis in Hightstock ,

```
navigator: {
        enabled: true
    },
```

By default it will add a navigator for X-Axis,
but some users want to add a navigator for Y-Axis while keep the X-Axis.
Here is how this problem goes : https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2364547-add-navigation-bar-for-y-axis-in-highstock

seems still not add the feature in the official lib?

Comment: The ticket you posted doesn't have "COMPLETED" flag, so it's not implemented in the core ;)

Comment: Do you know other ways to implement it?

Comment: Use [chart.renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) to manually create navigator with all options and features. I assume this is a lot of work to do, otherwise it would be already in the Highstock core ;)